# iptables not forwarding traffic from 80 to 8000

Tags: iptables

iptables is proving to be a very complicated tool for me to use. I'm trying to do the following:

1. Accept all packets on 80, 443, 22
2. Forward packets received from 80 to 8000
3. Accept packets from only one specific IP address on port 8096

The problem is that right now only SSH works, the web server isn't being forwarded any traffic. 
Note: The web server is indeed running on port 8000. `curl localhost:8000` spits html.

Here are my rules `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

```
root@mybox:~# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8000
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8000

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And

```
root@mybox:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Do you have enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward` ?

Comment: yes, it's set to 1.

Comment: How do you try to verify your results? Connecting from an external host OR simply curl localhost ?

Comment: Both, I cannot connect to the server (by IP) over port 80 when viewed in multiple browsers. I *can* however curl the localhost at port 8000 (when SSH'd in)

Comment: Can you curl port 80 from localhost? Could be that you only listen on port 8000 on the `lo` interface and only listen on port 80 on the internet-facing interface.

Comment: @Jorn, I installed nginx and reversed all traffic to the local IP. This isn't a solution to understanding iptables, but it solves the problem.

Comment: Could you enable logs for iptables and see if the traffic is not blocked? Shouldn't you have ACCEPT rule for port 8000 in your INPUT chain?